# 4 partitions and 3 similar Os: it's possible without problems?

Tags: lubuntu, partitioning

is it possible to create 4 partitons, one ubuntu, one lubuntu, one puppylinux, and one (much bigger) just data? and after run each time a different Os, but reading the same data partition? I mean without problems? for problems I mean that maybe one of them create/modify a file and the others cannot read it, or the others aren't able to read the whole partition at all. I think there shouldn't be any problems, because they all originated from linux, but I ask just to be sure.
(offtopic: sure somebody will say it's pointless, but I just want to compare the 3 Os separately, and not on a live cd, and for a few weeks, in a more stable situation or everyday life)

Comment: and how much space is recommended for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with four Operating Systems so three is definitely possible.  I had no problems.  I allocated about 30 Gbs for each system and it was plenty.